# How can I do addition with human words?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do addition with human words. My code takes the input, slices every word, and pushes into an array called DL. This works without any issues, and if you `console.log` it out, it does this:

```
[ 'add' ]
[ 'add', '6' ]
[ 'add', '6', 'and' ]
[ 'add', '6', 'and', '4' ]
```

Now I have an array in the code that are supposed to act as 'operators'. It looks like this:

```
var operator = [
  "add",
  "sub",
  "mul",
  "div"
]
```

Now I want to loop through the DL array to see if one of the operators is in DL. If this case passes true, I want to add 6 and 4 together, and the code will print out 10.

This is the full code:

```
function output(func) {
  console.log(func)
}

var operator = [
 "add",
 "sub",
 "mul",
 "div"
]

var dl = []

const read = string => {
   return string.split(' ').map(item => {
      dl.push(item.trim())
      console.log(dl)
   })
}


var main = read(
  `add 6 and 4`
)

output(main)
```

Comment: does your array contain only two numbers ?

Comment: yes, but i don't mind having more, so something like add 6 and 4 and 5 should be valid too.

Comment: What's the question you have about your code?

Comment: @jarmod Check if DL has one of the operators in the operators array, then if it returns true, add 6 and 4.

Answer (score 0):

first, separate the operators and numbers from the array , you can either separate these two inside a `.map` or use a separate `.filter`

```
const operator = dl.find(x=>x.includes("add" , "sub" , "mul", "del"))
const numbers =  dl.filter(x=>Number(x))
```

then use a separate function to do the operations like

```
console.log(output())

function output(){
switch(operator){
case "add":
return numbers.reduce((a, b) => Number(a) +Number(b));
case "sub":
// your logic here
// rest of the operators logic

}

}
```